Iterating a Landsat image collection to display as a layer in google earth engine
I am working with Landsat 8/9 in Google Earth Engine (GEE) and would like some help. I have a list of Landsat images and want to do dNBR calculations to each of them and later displaying each as a layer. I get this list using variable dates so I believe it would be best to have a function where I can iterate over the list, apply the calculation and then display the scene using a designated name. I pretty new to GEE so I wanted to ask for help. I would greatly appreciate some guidance. Thank you!
I wrote code that displays images using specific numbers for example:
var img1 = ee.Image(listofImages.get(0));
but this relies heavily on me editing the code to get each layer.
These image do not have the NBR calculation applied to it but I believe:
.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B7'])
should work within a function that can iterate throughout the list as well as subtracting the scene by the prefire scene to get the dNBR by using:
var dNBR= preNBR.subtract(postNBR)
